# In Lisp how can I check stream to see if it's empty without modifying it?

Tags: common-lisp

How can I check if the stream is empty without modifying it?  At the moment I'm using peek-char to see if there a character, but it appears to wait for the user to enter something if nothing new is in the stream.  Also, I don't know how to compare to an eof character... #\Space clearly won't work.  Help please?

```
    (loop while (equal (peek-char) '#\Space) 
        do (print 'testword))
```

Comment: Have you tried listen instead of peek-char?

Comment: I barely know how to use lisp. I tried stream-listen, which sounds like exactly what I want, but the program I have(lisp-works) appears to not know what that function is.  If you could give me guidance on how to implement it, that would be awesome.

Comment: Nevermind. I must have mistyped my code when I played with it earlier.  This appears to work perfect. Thank you.  And it's such a simple solution.

Comment: You should not quote the character literal.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the manual:

[LISTEN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listen.htm) checks if there is input available.

[PEEK-CHAR](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_peek_c.htm) can either signal an error at eof or return an eof value. You can also tell it what eof value to return.